# Gitlab private repo to include multiple auth token in CI/CD variables

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

With reference to the [Gitlab document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html)

I can use one configuration to access on private docker image repo.

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.example.com:5000": {
            "auth": "base64.... token"
        }
    }
}
```

this is set to DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG variable, but the CI/CD has a stage which access two different private Docker repo, which have different Auth token.

Is it possible to include more than one auth token, like below

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "registry1.com:5000": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 1"
        },
        {
        "registry2.com:5000": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works exactly like that. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#configure-a-job):

> You can add configuration for as many registries as you want, adding more registries to the "auths" hash as described above.